# How to print the items in q, the async way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Here is a program i'm trying wrap my head around with, how do i print the items in the q properly, once all the results are pushed ?

```
function asyncAdd(a,b,callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        return callback(a+b);
    },0);
}

var q = [];
var ctr = 0;
for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    (function(i) {
       var res = asyncAdd(i, 0, printRes);
       q.push(res);
    })(i);
}


function done(q) {
    console.log("done"+q);
}

function printRes(res) {
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You're doing it correctly to where each individual push is an individual async operation and each operation will print when it's complete. If you want it to print only after all the async operations are complete you need to know how many operations are going to performed then keep count of how many are completed...when these numbers match you know all async operations are done

Comment: @Literphor The Promise spec also has a nice `Promise.all` that will wait till all promises are done.  Since A+ Promise Libraries are compatible with each other, that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my version

```
function asyncAdd(a,b,callback) {
    callback(a+b);
}

var q = [];
var ctr = 0;
var max = 9;
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    asyncAdd(i, 0, printRes);       
}


function done(q) {
    console.log("done " + q);
}

function printRes(res) {
    q.push(res);
    if (q.length === max)
        done(q);
}
```